# Process contents in array based on type in shellscript

Tags: bash, shell

I have an array that has three types of data in it, integer, integer/integer, and the string value.
I have shown a sample below.

```
myarr = (2301/2320,Team Lifeline, 2311, 7650/7670, 232)
```

I have the following algorithm that I want to come up with.

```
For index in myarr
  if index contains data as number1/number2; then
     create an array, "mynumbers" to hold all the numbers starting from number1 to number2
  else if index is a string
     add it in "mystrarr"
  else 
     add it in "myintarr"
done
```

For the first case, if I have an enter in the `myarr` as `2301/2320`, 
then the `mynumbers` as shown in the pseudocode will have entries from `{2301, 2302, ... , 2320}.` I am not able to understand on how to parse the entry in `myarr` and identify that it has a `/` in the array.

For the second situation, I am also not sure on how to identify if the entry in the  `myarr` and know it is a string. `mystrarr` should have `{Team Lifeline}`.

For the final case, the `myintarr` should have `{2311, 232}`.

Any help would be appreciated. I am very new to shell script.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Overflow is not a coding service.... but I was bored so here you go...

```
#!/bin/bash

myarr=(2301/2320 'Team Lifeline' 2311 7650/7670 232)

for element in "${myarr[@]}"; do
    if [[ $element =~ ^[0-9]+/[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        range="{${element%/*}..${element##*/}}"
        mynumbers=( $(eval "echo $range") )
    elif [ $element -eq $element ] 2>> /dev/null; then
        intarr+=( $element )
    else
        strarr+=( "$element" )
    fi
done

echo "mynumbers = ${mynumbers[*]}"
echo "intarr = ${intarr[*]}"
echo "strarr = ${strarr[*]}"
```

A lot to unpack here for inexperienced.  So ask questions where I didn't cover anything.  Things to note:

- All assignments there are no spaces around `=`.
- Array assignments are of the format `( element1 element2 ... )`
- Appending to arrays with `+=(...)` format
- Looping through array elements `for element in "${myarr[@]}"`

**Note** that the array generated by 7650/7670 will overwrite the array generated by 2301/2320.  I assume you have some kind of plan for this array, so I didn't do anything to stop it from being overwritten.

**More details**

This line is validating the format for 111/222:

```
if [[ $element =~ ^[0-9]+/[0-9]+$ ]]; then
```

- `[[ x =~ x ]]` performs a regex comparison and this regex essentially just means:
- `^` - beginning of the string
- `[0-9]+` - Atleast 1 number
- `/` - character literal
- `$` - end of string

These lines are expanding your beginning and ending numbers:

```
range="{${element%/*}..${element##*/}}"
mynumbers=( $(eval "echo $range") )
```

This is maybe more complicated than it needs to be as most people try to avoid `eval` in general for security reasons.  I'm leveraging bash's brace expansion.  If you run `echo {5..9}`, it will output `5 6 7 8 9`.  This does not trigger with variables, so I cheated and used `eval`.

This line is checking if we are dealing with an integer:

```
[ $element -eq $element ] 2>> /dev/null
```

This works by running an integer `-eq` (equals) comparison on the variable against itself.  This will actually fail and throw an error message on anything but an integer.  This is not the way it was designed to be used which is why we discard all the error messages (`2>> /dev/null`).

This is a nice succinct script, but is using some unconventional practices.  A longer more verbose version may be better for a beginner.

Comment: I am currently understanding your solution. Thanks for the detailed answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [regular expressions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) to match elements that are nothing but digits, or digits/digits, and assume everything else is a string:

```
#!/bin/bash

myarr=(2301/2320 "Time Lifeline" 2311 7650/7670 232)
declare -a mynumbers mystrarr myintarr

for elem in "${myarr[@]}"; do
    if [[ $elem =~ ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ ]]; then
        mynumbers+=($(seq ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}))
    elif [[ $elem =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        myintarr+=($elem)
    else
        mystrarr+=("$elem")
    fi
done

echo mynumbers is "${mynumbers[@]}"
echo myintarr is "${myintarr[@]}"
echo mystrarr is "${mystrarr[*]}"
```

---

Jason explained a lot in his (very similar; there's only so many obvious ways to do this) answer, so to expand on where ours are different:

We both use regular expressions to match the `integer/integer` case, but he then goes on to extract the two numbers using parameter expansion with pattern removal options, while mine captures the two integers in the regular expression, and uses the `BASH_REMATCH` array to access their values as well as the `seq` command to generate the numbers between the two.

Comment: +1 I like yours better.  You avoid `eval` and `[[ $elem =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]` is more explicit than my `-eq` hack.